# Error when I am parsing string value to integer

Tags: java, android, parsing

I get the data from bluetooth , this data it is string type and I am trying to parse this value to integer in android studio and I get this error "java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int:" so what can I do to resolve it.
This is my java code :

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

        stopWorker = false;
        readBufferPosition = 0;
        readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker) {
                    try {
                        int bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();
                        if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            inputStream.read(packetBytes);
                            for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                                byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                if (b == delimiter) {
                                    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                    final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                    readBufferPosition = 0;

                                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {

                                            if(Integer.parseInt(data)<10) {//Here the error

                                                addNotification();
                                            }

                                            System.out.println(data);
                                        }
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        stopWorker = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Print your "data" to log. Then you will find our what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what value do you receive in data. but I can say that NumberFormatException comes when you try to convert a string into Int which is not valid Int.
Example :

String data="ABC";
will throw an exception while converting it into Integer. As "ABC" is not an integer.

Hence could you check what value exactly are you getting in data?
Also, add a try-catch block

```
try{
    int i = Integer.parseInt(input);
} catch(NumberFormatException ex){ // handle your exception
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use `Integer.parseInt(String)`, your string data must only have numbers or ASCII value of `+` and `-` otherwise, it throws `NumberFormatException`.

> public static int parseInt(String s)
>                       throws NumberFormatException
>
> Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The characters
>   in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first
>   character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a
>   negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a
>   positive value.
>
> [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not reciving an int value. Check what data contains, maybe it contains some character unexpected.